# GUI declarative language implementation

Tags: c++, user-interface, declarative

I've recently begun working on a project regarding GUI building using some form of declarative language. What i mean is that i need to describe an hierarchy of objects, without specifying the type of GUI widgets that will be used to "show" that hierarchy. For example, for some existing hierarchy **H**, using JSON notation (or something like that):

```
H = 
{
    "title" : "Label_1"
    "children" : 
    [
        {
            "title" : "Label_2"
            "children": 
            [
                {
                    "title": "Field_A"
                    "type": "Integer"
                    "value": 10
                },

                {
                    "title": "Field_B"
                    "type": "String"
                    "value": "YES"
                }
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Someone could build a simple window, that would be shown to the user by pressing a button labeled "Label_1". The window could be then titled "Label_2"
and have two fields labeled "Field_A" and "Field_B" accepting integer and boolean
values respectively.

Someone else, could put this hierarchy on a tree list, e.g

```
--------------------------------------------------------
>Label_1                |
    >Label_2            |
        >Field_A        |   10
        >Field_B        |   YES
```

My first question is, well, do i have to build some form of a language parser to achieve something like this ? Could i use JSON then ? Though i don't need to support complex hierarchies, there is need to support mutually exclusive hierarchies (something like radio buttons enabling/disabling options). I have the feeling that it looks like some form of language parsing with a couple of operators. Don't get me wrong, i am of a Mechanical Engineering background, and i am not an experienced programmer.

Thank you in advance for your comments and help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON would be one choice. XML would be another -- for example, Microsoft uses [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747122.aspx) (an XML dialect) for exactly this purpose and the W3C has a (fairly new) [Widget packaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/) specification (using another dialect of XML). Any of these will let you use existing parsers instead of building yet another from the ground up.

Comment: So, i guess i am moving at the right direction then. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, if it's about declarative / c++ / ui why did not "http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/05/13/qt-declarative-ui/" come to anybody's mind?

Comment: *amn that closing `"`! what about http://qt.nokia.com/doc/qml-snapshot/declarativeui.html?

Answer (score 5):

**What you're looking for is called QML**

It's Qt's GUI declarative language based on JSON.

I'm was wondering the same thing so I started a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962874/where-is-the-open-source-alternative-to-wpf) to collect information on Open Source, declarative GUI languages. If you're looking for alternatives, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I am just testing QML for a real user interface environment on a C++ project based on Qt.
And I think it is very powerful as a declarative language so if you already know some Qt basics you can use it.

You can build modern, professional and good-looking user interfaces very very fast. And you can also effortless connect the declarative language with your C++ code and vice versa.